# Is it a good idea to generate short URLs with non-ASCII characters?

Tags: url, non-ascii-characters

Given I want to generate short urls and I want to keep it as short as possible, is it a good idea to add non-ASCII characters in the path?

URL could look like [https://example.com/hžйÄю](https://example.com/h%C5%BE%D0%B9%C3%84%D1%8E)

**Possible pros:**

- Many possible combinations
- Addresses will be short even if there are thousands of them

**Possible cons:**

- No user will ever be able to write it without installing/enabling a variety of keyboard layouts, let alone remember it
- Some Operating systems may not be able to interpret the characters

Is it even worth considering doing this?

Comment: [URLs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) are **not allowed** to have *unescaped* non-ASCII characters in them at all, only *non-reserved* ASCII characters can appear as-is.  [IRIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987), on the other hand, allow unescaped Unicode characters.